# Searching for items in breadcrumbs and displaying them in flat list

Tags: search-results, breadcrumbs

We've got a highly structured hierarchy, which can be navigated using breadcrumbs. It does contain same keyword in some edge cases.

So imagine that our hierarchy looks like this:

1. Beer

   - Beer By Type

     - Beer Type 1
     - Beer Type 2
     - Beer Type 3
   - Beer By Origin

     - Beer Origin 1
     - Beer Origin 2
     - Beer Origin 3
     - Beer Origin 4
     - Beer Origin 5

And so on. There are some edge cases where we have around 500 categories with *Beer* in its name.

Now the issue is that our system can run a search in this hierarchy and present a flat list of categories.

It works fine, if user is quite specific or sub-hierarchy is not too nested, however users are left out without context (path to specific category) and it gets even worse when you're getting 500 categories back in this edge case.

Sample use case:

1. User types in a search box
2. User gets list below
3. Imagine what happens if there are over 500 categories
4. *Pardon my mockup skills*

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLqchL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

How would someone fix it by adding context to each item and not overwhelming user with tons of selections?

Comment: If I understand right you want breadcrumbs to make it clear for people 'how far they're in' A possibility is to use dots like Home > beer type > ... > beer type 1 or something.

Comment: could you clarify what's the purpose of this? I mean, what do users need? To search items? Categories? etc

Comment: @KeesSonnema That's correct. There are two problems here. When a flat list is present, user loses context(how deep in hierarchy they are)

Comment: @rewobs, Searching categories in hierarchy. I'll update answer and include sample use case.

Comment: why do they need to know how deep in the hierarchy they are?

Comment: Keep in mind that it needs to be as easy as possible for the users. Don't show data which isn't needed to understand. It will only confuse users.

Comment: @rewobs so they could select it manually in the future without typing stuff into search bar(?) and seeing sibling categories. I'm just a developer, trying to simplify this. I've been thrown quite a lot of solutions and none of them make sense, that's why I'm askin here. I'm looking for something neat, simple and friendly for end user.

Comment: I've already written an answer but not posted yet because I don't know if it's well aimed. What about let the users search for whatever word/s they want, and afterwards filter them? Something like ecommerce sites, you first search for an item with vague words, and then start filtering till your get where you want, it seems the most natural thing if the goal is to reach to some item or category/subcateogyr. Tell me if it could work so I know if my answer will apply.

Comment: @rewobs You mean faceted search? I've suggested this to BAs, but they're doubting about it. For me, it seems like a solution. This would be quite a huge project in our case, however they want something relatively quick... *who could've thought*...

Comment: Yes, that way. Im a programmer too and implementing a basic filter is not a big deal. I'll post the answer and you can comment there if something wont work for some reason and maybe I could think of something else.

Comment: I'm just worried what you would display in a facets? You have to tie some sort of connections between items (taxonomies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of forcing a way of reaching a item/category, I would try the oppossite, first show the childs and filter by its parents. There's something e-commerce sites do.

Just **show the most relevant results** (most popular, most selled, etc) and let the users filter afterwards.

For example, Ebay uses a left panel for category filter, offers "related searchs" at the top and a dropdown for category search too.

The important thing is to **give the users choices and paths to get to the results they want** to keep it natural for them, you can't do magic if there are thousands results.

Additionally you could be the users the chance to **"pin" a certain category** so **they can later access it directly**.

[image]

Comment: I know it's quite hard to tell what would be recommended facets, when you don't know what data is available, but perhaps you have some suggestions? If no, I'll wait a while to accept your answer, in case someone will come with something outstanding (I just don't want to un-accept your answer)

Comment: "when you don't know what data is available" Are you telling me that the users won't know what they are looking for until they navigate through cathegories? (like pure discovering) If so, that's not a normal behavior or use case, if users see a search bar they will run to it an try to search. If for some reason they don't have an idea what's searchable, the home page should orient them.

Comment: No, pardon my english. I was wondering whether you can suggest some broadly used facet-types, but at the same time I was implying that it would be hard to do it for you without knowing data(categories that we have in our trees). Just ignore it.